# Can DST transitions cause "random" query timeouts?

Tags: sql-server, timezone, virtualisation, ado.net, query-timeout

I have encountered a query timeout ("Execution Timeout Expired") on a sub-second query on a connection set to 30 seconds timeouts.  Client side logging indicated that 4 days elapsed between submitting the query and receiving the timeout.  The client and the server were both running as part of the same virtual machine.

The root cause was fairly evident: the virtual machine, having been suspended over several days, synchronized its system time via NTP and jumped 4 days ahead in time and the system time adjustment propagated to SQL Server just as it was executing the unfortunate query.  However, this incident got us thinking.

**Can transitions to daylight saving time cause random query timeouts, by spuriously adding 1 hour to the measured execution time of the query?**

**Can other time zone changes cause random query timeouts?**

I am hoping that SQL Server would use UTC timestamps to detect query timeouts and thus be unaffected by time zone changes.  But I am unable to find any documentation to this effect.

Comment: The SQL Server database engine doesn't detect query timeouts; it is the SQL Server client API that cancels queries that run too long. Add the client API you are using to your question as the answer may vary by driver implementation.

Comment: Agreed with Dan, this has nothing to do with SQL Server, and all to do with the client-side.

Comment: @DanGuzman - Thank you Dan, added the ado.net tag.  Already knowing that SQL Server as such isn't involved is a large part of the answer.  But I'm even more puzzled now because .NET ReferenceSource implementation appears to be using timer ticks since system start-up rather than DateTime.Now, so I don't quite get how the VM suspend period causes the query timeout.